# Validate name only with 'alphabets', 'spaces' and 'periods' in jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using `jquery.validate.min.js` file for validations. I want to allow only alphabets, spaces and periods in the `username` field. How to show the message?

Comment: You want help writing a regex or help with how to make/use a custom rule? Have you already looked at all the rules included in [the additional-methods.js file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js)? Where is your code?  Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

**Try this :**

**Demo :**  http://jsfiddle.net/bJ4Tz/4/

**jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").keypress(function (e){
        var code =e.keyCode || e.which;
        if((code<65 || code>90)&&(code<97 || code>122)&&code!=32&&code!=46)  
        {
          alert("Only alphabates are allowed");
          return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**Textbox code :**

```
<input type="text" id="text"/>
```

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he was using the jQuery Validate plugin.